# How do I get a folder to stop forgetting its sorting options?

Tags: finder

I have a folder (my home folder) which I like to have in icon view and kept arranged by name.

However, every day or so it seems to forget the sorting - although the view options panel seems to think that the option is still valid.   I have to change it to arrange by another criterion and then re-select arrange by name.

This is rather irritating, to say the least.  Does anyone know how to fix the Finder's forgetfulness

[image]

Comment: "Arrange by Name" is a one-time command to arrange the icons. When an item in the folder gets deleted, or new ones added, they don't adhere to this rule, until you force another "Arrange by Name". It looks like this is the behavior you are seeing. The solution is to choose "Sort by Name", but I notice that option is greyed out. If that is the case, I would close the Finder window and run the following command in Terminal: `rm ~/.DS_Store`. This will remove a hidden file that contains the folder display information. You will have to set the folder settings again after this but it should work.

Comment: Thanks - how stupid of me.  It's rather a confusing set of options though isn't it!

Comment: Since my comment worked, I made it the answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Arrange by Name" is a one-time command to arrange the icons. When an item in the folder gets deleted, or new ones added, they don't adhere to this rule, until you force another "Arrange by Name". It looks like this is the behavior you are seeing.

The solution is to choose "Sort by Name", which applies an ongoing rule.